# Access synthesized properties when using ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

When I declare the synthesis a property like this:

```
@syntesize myObject = _myObject;
```

I can access `_myObject` directly in code, while avoiding the synthesized getters and setters.

However, if I synthesize the property like this

```
 @syntesize myObject = myObject;
```

will I no longer be able to access the instance variable hidden behind `= myObject`? Should I have a preference in using one or the other. Because I have often experienced "`BAD_ACCESS` - problems" when using `_myObject` instead of `self.myObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases you can access the underlying ivar. In both cases you should avoid doing so. Use accessors everywhere except init, dealloc and within accessors themselves. This will avoid many headaches, with or without ARC.

That said, if you're getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when accessing the ivar under ARC, you likely are doing one of the following:

- incorrect use of `__bridge`
- using `assign` or `__unsafe_unretained` unsafely

Comment: +1 and also: declared properties are accessors. @Besi, your code only uses accessors with dot syntax (`self.myObject`) or explicitly (`[self myObject]` or `[self setMyObject:...]`). So, declared properties do not hide or conflict with the instance variable name. There's no ambiguity about which is used in any given expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a property, then you should use the property accessors and avoid using the instance variable directly. The only exceptions are in your `-init` and `-dealloc` methods, and in most cases it's fine to use the accessors there too. Don't avoid the accessors, *use* them.

Answer (score 1):

Using `_myObject` in and of itself shouldn't cause memory management problems. The cause almost certainly lies somewhere else or is much more subtle than simply using an underscore prefixed ivar name. Anyway, if you name the ivar the same as the property, you can still access the instance variable by using just its name, as usual. It's only when you access it via the accessor methods (using e.g. either `self.myObject` or `[self myObject]`) that you're not directly accessing the ivar. You can also access it using `self->myObject`, which is equivalent to just `myObject`.

All that said, I consider it good practice to only access ivars directly inside the accessor method implementations themselves, along with `init` (and `dealloc` if not using ARC).

Comment: I am not sure if that is true. Assuming you have a `strong` property and set an object without using `self.myObject` but rather with _myObject then this object is not retained because the synthesized "retain-accessor" is not called. So I might get `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` when doing this. Do you know what I mean...

Comment: As long as you let the compiler synthesize the instance variable by not declaring it explicitly*, if your @property is declared using `strong`, the resultant synthesized `_myObject` ivar will have an ownership qualifier of `__strong`, and the compiler will insert a retain (and a release of the prior value) when you assign a value to the variable.

This is spelled out in section 4.1.1 of the LLVM ARC documentation: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html .

*(if you declare the ivar explicitly, its ownership must match the ownership specified in the @property declaration)

Comment: I was not aware of the fact that any existing instance variables have the same ownership rules associated with it. Thanks for the valuable insight!